# How to access website on client machine as secure web in Localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I created system for school .net core MVC and configured it on Windows Server 2019 and IIS. for server work fine access in Internet Exprorer (secure website) But for chrome invalid for certificate.
and then for client not secure too access my server website.  I read many tutorial but didnt help me.
.
.
already follow this tutorial https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/install-ssl-certificate-in-localhost-website-iis
and setup self certificate in IIS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need to install the certificate on the clients if it's self-signed.

Comment: @Fildor ohhh,,  so if I have 10 client, I need to Install every my client @Fildor?

Comment: It's been a while since I had to wrestle with IIS but if I remember correctly, then yes. The thing is: You are using a self-signed cert. So your clients do not have a means to verify against some preinstalled Certificate Authority. That's why you need to tell them "If you see this certificate, it's valid. Believe me, I know." It works on your server, because (I guess) it has been installed during creation.

Comment: any advice for I installed certificate Server inside?  FYI this is local website,,

Comment: @DingPeng I don't have button export to file and Install Certificate?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: You can try to click the icon in the URL address bar, which will prompt you to export the certificate.

Comment: not yet @DingPeng,,,    still same not secure for client,,  or maybe because use IP

Comment: Have you installed the certificate to the client?

Comment: One more thing to note is that the name of the domain you are trying to access needs to match the domain name contained in the certificate.

Comment: The IP address cannot be filled in the URL field. The name of the domain to be used must match the domain name contained in the certificate.

Comment: I update my reply.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a self-signed certificate, and the client must install this certificate into a trusted root certificate to establish a trust relationship.

Here is a demo:

I used Server certificates to create a self-signed certificate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After clicking OK, the following self-signed certificate will be generated:

[image]

Then we need to set up an SSL certificate for the website:

[image]

When we visit for the first time, we will be prompted that this site is not secure, because the self-signed certificate is not in our trusted zone:

[image]

We need to export and install this certificate into our trusted zone:

[image]

Then we need to install this certificate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then click OK until the installation is successful.

After successful installation, we visit again and now we have established a trust relationship:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

In the above example, we can only access the service through the following URL:

**htts://vpedin456vm**

And cannot use IIS IP address.

Comment: my web not appear for export and install certificate,

Comment: You can export the certificate generated by the server and install it on the client.

Comment: Find the generated self-signed certificate and export it.